# Gimp 2: Brush tool (and others) are full-hardness like pencil tool

Tags: gimp, image-editing

This is hard to explain as I don't know the proper terminology, but basically the usual behaviour of the brush tool is to mix/fade it's edges with the background, but it doesn't do this for some of my images (others work fine). This:[image: Working and non-working brush tool] is a picture to show what I mean. Other tools that would also have a fade/blur effect, such as the text tool and eraser tools also have this broken behavior. [This](https://hijiribe.donmai.us/data/__common_raccoon_and_fennec_kemono_friends_drawn_by_tanaka_kusao__d406b28a5257401dbc78bca3ca4370af.png) is the image I was trying to edit ([here](https://danbooru.donmai.us/posts/2823813) is a non-hotlink if danbooru blocks you).

Anyway I'm just wondering if it's a settings issue that I accidentally changed, or something about the image, either way I want the old behavior back.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, the image was in "Indexed Mode", switching to "RGB Mode" in `image > mode` solved the problem.

Comment: Nitpicking: it was an indexed image with a limited color map, probably only black and white. You can get the output of your working image with an indexed image as well, if its color map happens to contain many or even all 256 shades of grey.